# C# Unable to exit thread.

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

New to the threading and its concepts. I have following code where I am using Windows.Forms in console app to print a webpage.

My Code looks like below:

My Application does print the page but it never exists . its stuck at `Application.Run();`

How do I make my application exit? 
Thanks for helping out.

( if I use `Application.DoEvents();` wb.print(); does not print. )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebBrowserWithoutAForm
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool completed = false;
        private static WebBrowser wb;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
            wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

            while (!completed)
            {
                //Application.DoEvents();
                Application.Run();
            }
            Console.Write("\n\nDone with it!\n\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
            wb.Print();
            completed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever use `Application.DoEvents()`. It's only in the framework for backward compatibility with VB6. It will create hard-to-resolve bugs in your code. It is always a better option to use something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN for [Application.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> In a Win32-based or Windows Forms application, a message loop is a
>   routine in code that processes user events, such as mouse clicks and
>   keyboard strokes. Every running Windows-based application requires an
>   active message loop, called the main message loop. When the main
>   message loop is closed, the application exits. In Windows Forms, this
>   loop is closed when the `Exit` method is called, or when the
>   `ExitThread` method is called on the thread that is running the main
>   message loop.

The Exit method this talks about is `Application.Exit`.